# PlayFramework and jquery chart

Tags: java, json, jquery, playframework

i'm trying to use https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView
in play 1.2.4

already check [JQuery GanttChart - Apply Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370988/jquery-ganttchart-apply-data)

but my problem is how to renderJSON to the view,

i have try a simple one that is renderJSON("Hello"); and capture in the view, the problem is that i only manage to download a file like 4fporLKs.part1 that have inside Hello :(

can some one explain me how to do it

thanks

Answer (score 1):

other guy is working in the same as i, but haven't got it

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {

        $("#ganttChart").ganttView({ 
           data : 'dataUrl: "data.json"',
            slideWidth: 900,
            behavior: {
                onClick: function (data) { 
                    var msg = "You clicked on an event: { start: " + data.start.toString("M/d/yyyy") + ", end: " + data.end.toString("M/d/yyyy") + " }";
                    $("#eventMessage").text(msg);
                },
                onResize: function (data) { 
                    var msg = "You resized an event: { start: " + data.start.toString("M/d/yyyy") + ", end: " + data.end.toString("M/d/yyyy") + " }";
                    $("#eventMessage").text(msg);
                },
                onDrag: function (data) { 
                    var msg = "You dragged an event: { start: " + data.start.toString("M/d/yyyy") + ", end: " + data.end.toString("M/d/yyyy") + " }";
                    $("#eventMessage").text(msg);
                }
            }
        });

        //$("#ganttChart").ganttView("setSlideWidth", 600);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`"hello"` is not well formated json string, try:

```
renderJSON("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
```

Also check [Play's documentation for controllers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers) to see how render ie. json from List (paragraph: **Return a JSON String**)

Comment: that is what i have try, but comes as a file, how to capture the file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your intention, could you describe it with more details?

Comment: biesior, thanks for the interest  , basic the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370988/jquery-ganttchart-apply-data/10123823#10123823

how ever, this is not working because data is not equal to data.json